# How to display owl carousel on page other than homepage in Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify, owl-carousel

I currently have an owl carousel that I have added onto my homepage on my shopify store and this all works fine. What I was looking to find out is that I have added Pages that display text, but at the bottom of this, I would like to display another carousel slider but not sure how I call this.

Currently, I have the following in my theme.

liquid file:

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function () {
    var carousel = $("#owl-demo");
    carousel.owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    margin:10,
    navigation:true,
    autoHeight : true,
    autoPlay : 3000,
    navigationText: [
      "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
      "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"
      ],
  });
});
</script>
```

and my index.liquid file has the following:

```
<div class="carousel-bg">

    <div class="wrapper-with-margin">
      <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
        <div><img src="{{ 'carousel-slider1.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}"></div>
        <div><img src="{{ 'carousel-slider2.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}"></div>
        <div><img src="{{ 'carousel-slider3.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>   

  </div>
```

I have added the same code into my page code, but nothing shows up.

If somebody could please if I am calling this right, would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added that `script` on your page code too?

Comment: Juan Ferreras, I haven't added the script to the page, just replicated the code from my index.liquid for the slider images.

Comment: That script code needs to run on your page as it is what initialized Owl Carousel. I don't know where it is (you've mentioned _liquid_ file), but make sure it's executing on this new page and not only on `index.liquid`

Comment: Thanks Juan, I will add the script into my page code and see how I get on.